How to pass a form into Angular Material dialog
I need to create a reusable form dialog to visualize different forms. I am using Angular 17 and Angular Material. In my component I am trying to define a form like that:


<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm)">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" name="date" ngModel required>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.date.invalid && myForm.controls.date.touched">Please choose a date.</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" ngModel required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.firstName.invalid && myForm.controls.firstName.touched">Please enter a first name.</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>



In my .ts file I have a method to open a dialog:


@ViewChild('myForm', { static: true }) public myForm: ElementRef;

public openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FilterFormDialogComponent, {
        width: '460px',
        disableClose: true,
        autoFocus: false,
        panelClass: 'form-dialog',
        data: {
            form: this.myForm // reference to the form previously defined
        },
    });
}



In my filterFormDialogComponent I am trying to visualize the inserted form in its html by using ng-content. However, I am unable to visualize the form.
Is it possible to pass a form or another component into a dialog by using MAT_DIALOG_DATA? If so, how to display it properly into the html of the dialog?

You might still get into trouble with content projection, but for starters, myForm is of type NgForm (not ElementRef), because you have #myForm="ngForm" (not just #myForm).
